# Troubleshooting Flask Web App Deployment on Netlify from GitHub

Tags: python, flask, web, netlify

I'm deploying a web app on Netlify, and I'm facing a 'Page Not Found' error when I access the website. I'm using Python with the Flask library, and my deployment is from a GitHub repository. Any insights into why this error is occurring?

I attempted to deploy my Flask web app on Netlify from my GitHub repository. I expected the website to load without any issues. However, I encountered a 'Page Not Found' error when I tried to access the site.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.